# What's the difference between the different "rename" commands?

Tags: command-line, packaging, perl, rename

Since Ubuntu 14.04 there are at least three `rename` commands:

1. `rename` provided by the `util-linux` package, see [man rename.ul](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html)
2. `rename` provided by the `perl` package, see [man prename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/prename.1.html)
3. `rename` provided by the `rename` package, see [man file-rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html)

Questions:

- What exactly are the differences between those commands?
- How come there are multiple packages providing different commands using the same name – I suppose that's not an accident, or is it?
- Wouldn't it be rather straightforward for the `perl` package to either include the “full” `rename` command or not include any `rename` command at all? Why is this seemingly uncomplete split sustained until at least Ubuntu 17.04?

This question has already been asked on U&L (as I found out later):
[What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/246819)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How come there are two packages providing different commands using the same name (if not by accident)?

That's not unusual. Authors typically pick the simplest command name they think of, so if two people write a command to rename files, it's likely they'll both name it `rename`. That's one of the reasons behind the [Debian Alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) - it allows packages providing similarly-named commands to coexist, and for one package to replace another. For example, there are multiple AWK implementations - `mawk`, `original-awk`, `gawk` (though they all refer to themselves as awk). With the alternatives system, you can install them all at the same time, and conveniently switch between any of them as the default `awk`.

In this specific case, `prename` comes from the Perl source code. The Debian package maintainers originally had `rename` be the Perl one, then switched to the alternatives system, to accommodate the `rename` from `util-linux`. Then somebody wrote an improved version of Perl's `rename` in [the File-Rename Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/lib/File/Rename.pm), which was then added as another alternative. But that's not even the only Perl module for renaming files.

> Wouldn't it be rather straightforward for the `perl` package to either include the “full” `rename` command or not include any `rename` command at all? Why is this seemingly uncomplete split sustained until at least Ubuntu 17.04?

See [Debian bug #735134](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=735134) for how this situation evolved. Debian maintainers generally prefer going at least one release when doing something drastic, like replacing a working command with another. `prename` was kept around for jessie, and has now been removed for buster. In addition, it looks like `rename` will no longer be under the alternatives system, since `rename.ul` is too incompatible. `rename` will be just `file-rename`.

Since Ubuntu generally picks up packaging changes from Debian, what happens to `rename` in Debian will be picked up by Ubuntu sooner or later, probably in 18.04. It seems to be too late for 17.10.

> What exactly are the differences between those commands?

Fundamentally, both `prename` and `file-rename` run Perl expressions to rename files. `file-rename` is just actively maintained and supports more options. `rename` from `util-linux` works entirely differently, has its own rules for patterns.

Comment: From [`man prename` for 17.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/prename.1p.html), it looks like 17.10 did in fact pick up `file-rename` instead of `prename`. Same for [18.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/prename.1p.html).