# Rename some files to their own name + something else

Tags: command-line, find, rename, mv

I have a directory like Photo

[image: Directory Picture!]

and I want to change the names of the directories inside it -> to what they are, but without it [www.faraDa...] like the first one that I change by `mv command`.
but I dont know how remove [www.faraD...] automatically ?
can do this by `find ... -exec or mv` in linux command or I need programing like python? to do it.

Update : in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

names are : `FVLNX9510` `A`to`z` `[www.FaraD...‍‍` They have a difference in the middle part of their name `A,B,C,D,...`.

Thank you all !

Comment: Please [edit] the question and clarify like Ubuntu version and some other details

Comment: I'd suggest using the `rename` command, but I don't understand your wanted name change sorry.

Comment: @Algnis Ok,I add system info in it but its Normal ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If the string to change is always the same in all files you could use this command:

```
rename \[www.website\]  '' *
```

This command works on Fedora 33 actually (I thought it was the same on Ubuntu), however this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-do-i-easily-rename-multiple-files-using-command-line) provides an extensive description on how to use `rename` on Ubuntu. I think that the command I wrote above should change in something like:

```
rename 's/\[www\.website\]//' *
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956010/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-rename-commands) you can find a description of different `rename` packages.

Comment: I think most people associate `rename` with Perl `File-Rename` with slightly different syntax. If you could state which rename command you use.

Comment: You are right, sorry! Let me edit my answer.

Comment: thank,but its different -> its is : `FVLNX9510` **`A`to`z`** `[www.FaraD...‍‍` They have a difference in the middle part of their name - `A B C D E F G ...`

Comment: @Sir-Sorg ok but if you need to remove the part between brackets [...] the command I posted above should do the work.

Comment: @overmach OK,I test it.but can do this by function of bash?

Comment: `for i in *; do mv "${i}" "${i::11}"; done`

Comment: @Sir-Sorg `mmv 'FVLNX9510 ? *' 'FVLNX9510 #1'` but I would still use `mmv` for this.