Rename files by changing the position of strings
I want to renaming several files with names, such as:
YL.BIRA..BHE.M.2001.324.210818.SAC

I want to rename it as:
YL.BIRA..M.2001.324.210818.BHE.SAC

I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/956010/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-rename-commands  and this for examples https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-do-i-easily-rename-multiple-files-using-command-line

Initially I thought you wanted to just remove that part ... To change the position, it could be something like rename -n 's/(.*\..*\.\.)([^.]*)(\.)(.*)(\.SAC)/$1$4.$2$5/' *.SAC

Treating all those dot-separated strings as fields, you could obtain that result by moving the 4th field to the (after having removed the 4th field) 8th position (pushing the 9th field to the right);
Using rename you may do:
rename -n '
    my @f = split(/\./);
    splice(@f, 7, 0, splice(@f, 3, 1));
    $_ = join(".", @f);
' *

Which will show what the result of the transformation would be if applied to all the elements in the current working directory:
% rename -n '
    my @f = split(/\./);
    splice(@f, 7, 0, splice(@f, 3, 1));
    $_ = join(".", @f);
' *
rename(YL.BIRA..BHE.M.2001.324.210818.SAC, YL.BIRA..M.2001.324.210818.BHE.SAC)

To actually apply the transformation, remove the -n switch:
rename '
    my @f = split(/\./);
    splice(@f, 7, 0, splice(@f, 3, 1));
    $_ = join(".", @f);
' *


Probably including a RegEx version as well would be useful as it would offer using the double .. as a sort of anchor given it's sort of unique ... I think :)

@Raffa I see your point, but my head was aching just trying to wrap my head around all those dots and parenthesis in your example, so I tried to avoid the burden to the best of my capabilities. The lenghts you go to slack... :) you should post your solution as an answer though, I think it's just as valid

Diversity is good, no doubt … But, your way is cleaner and neater and even in Bash I would probably choose reading each filename into an array with the . as IFS over using RegEx capture groups with Bash's builtin array for capturing groups and probably even over parameter expansion with glob patterns … It’s slack indeed as the .. might turn out to not be even consistent in all the filenames the OP has … So I'll probably keep it as a comment for the time being … Feel free to include it in your answer anytime though.

Although you tagged your question bash, if you are willing to switch to zsh you could use the contributed zmv module as follows (remove the -n after testing):
 % autoload -Uz zmv    # usually this would go in your ~/.zshrc

then
 % zmv -n -w '*.*..*.*.*.*.*.*' '$1.$2..$4.$5.$6.$7.$3.$8'
mv -- YL.BIRA..BHE.M.2001.324.210818.SAC YL.BIRA..M.2001.324.210818.BHE.SAC

or slightly more compactly
 % zmv -n '(*.*)..(*).(*.*.*.*).(*)' '$1..$3.$2.$4' 
mv -- YL.BIRA..BHE.M.2001.324.210818.SAC YL.BIRA..M.2001.324.210818.BHE.SAC

The first of these would also work in mmv (available from the Ubuntu "universe" repository) with minor changes:
$ mmv -n '*.*..*.*.*.*.*.*' '#1.#2..#4.#5.#6.#7.#3.#8'
YL.BIRA..BHE.M.2001.324.210818.SAC -> YL.BIRA..M.2001.324.210818.BHE.SAC

